# Read from text file using array - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, listview

I need help as I am trying to read a number of contacts from a textfile. I have seen some tutorials but data is hardcoded not saved in a text file. My text file name is "mytextfile.txt". This is were all my data is being saved. Now I would like to display it in the list view. So far this is where I ended up. Can anyone help pls? I am new to Android Studio. Thanks

```
public class AllContacts extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

ListView l;
String[] contacts={mytextfile.txt};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_contacts);

    l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contacts);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
    l.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
{
    TextView temp=(TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText()+""+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use File.lines that return a stream of the content of your file using the path of you file :

```
    File fileContact = new File("Indicate you path to the file here");
    String[] contacts = null;
    try {
       contacts = (String[]) Files.lines(fileContact.toPath())
                                  .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                                  .toArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // cant read the file
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I added a filter that check for every line in your file contact.txt that its not empty

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong you cant have the data from a file by just putting tge name in array, You need to read the content of the file so just read this [official document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for learning how to handle different data storage in android